# Cutting x-axis automatically when there is no data

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to make a ggplot with a time series. The problem is that I have a time gap between my data. So I would like to cut it out only when there is data available.

My code is down below. Please do not change the list into a dataframe because I need it like this. So far I have tried this:

```
w = 1
i = 2

library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_gray()) 
p1 = ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = df2[[w]], aes(x = df2[[w]]$Date, y = df2[[w]][,i]), stat="identity", color = "red") +
  geom_bar(data = df1[[w]], aes(x = df1[[w]]$Date, y = df1[[w]][,i]), stat="identity", color = "grey") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 9.142857, color="grey", size = 1.0)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 12.333333, color="red", size = 1.0)+
  scale_x_date(date_labels ="%m/%y",date_breaks  = "1 month")
p1
```

I have tried to add `facet_grid(bin ~ ., scale='free_x')` but then I am getting an error.

```
df1 = list(structure(list(Date = structure(c(17318, 17319, 17320, 17321, 
17322, 17323, 17324, 17325, 17326, 17327, 17328, 17329, 17330, 
17331, 17332, 17333, 17334, 17335, 17336, 17340, 17341, 17342, 
17343, 17344, 17345, 17346, 17347, 17348, 17349, 17350, 17351, 
17352, 17353, 17354, 17355, 17356, 17357, 17358, 17359, 17360, 
17361, 17362, 17363, 17364, 17365, 17366, 17367, 17368, 17369, 
17370, 17371, 17372, 17373, 17374, 17375, 17376, 17377, 17378, 
17379, 17380, 17381, 17382, 17383, 17384, 17385, 17386, 17387, 
17388, 17389, 17390, 17391, 17392, 17393, 17394, 17395, 17396, 
17397, 17398, 17399, 17400, 17401, 17402, 17403, 17404, 17405, 
17406, 17407, 17408, 17409, 17683, 17684, 17685, 17686, 17687, 
17688, 17689, 17690, 17691, 17692, 17693, 17694, 17695, 17696, 
17697, 17698, 17699, 17700, 17701, 17702, 17703, 17704, 17705, 
17706, 17707, 17708, 17709, 17710, 17711, 17712, 17713, 17714, 
17715, 17716, 17717, 17718, 17719, 17720, 17721, 17722, 17723, 
17724, 17725, 17726, 17727, 17728, 17729, 17730, 17731, 17732, 
17733, 17734, 17735, 17736, 17737, 17738, 17739, 17740, 17741, 
17748, 17749, 17750, 17751, 17752, 17753, 17754, 17755, 17756, 
17757, 17758, 17759, 17760, 17761, 17762, 17763, 17764, 17765, 
17766, 17767, 17768, 17769, 17770, 17771, 17772, 17773, 17774
), class = "Date"), G = c(20L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 
5L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
12L, 17L, 12L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 10L, 17L, 19L, 
10L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 
13L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 10L, 
6L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 
8L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 14L, 12L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 13L, 
7L, 12L, 11L, 5L, 8L, 17L, 15L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 
12L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 
6L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 
11L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 
11L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 6L, 4L, 14L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L)), .Names = c("Date", "G"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("152", "153", "154", "155", 
"156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", 
"165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "174", "175", "176", 
"177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", 
"186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", 
"195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", "203", 
"204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", "211", "212", 
"213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", "221", 
"222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", 
"231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", "238", "239", 
"240", "241", "242", "243", "517", "518", "519", "520", "521", 
"522", "523", "524", "525", "526", "527", "528", "529", "530", 
"531", "532", "533", "534", "535", "536", "537", "538", "539", 
"540", "541", "542", "543", "544", "545", "546", "547", "548", 
"549", "550", "551", "552", "553", "554", "555", "556", "557", 
"558", "559", "560", "561", "562", "563", "564", "565", "566", 
"567", "568", "569", "570", "571", "572", "573", "574", "575", 
"582", "583", "584", "585", "586", "587", "588", "589", "590", 
"591", "592", "593", "594", "595", "596", "597", "598", "599", 
"600", "601", "602", "603", "604", "605", "606", "607", "608"
)))

df2 = list(structure(list(Date = structure(c(17337, 17338, 17339, 17742, 
17743, 17744, 17745, 17746, 17747), class = "Date"), G = c(11L, 
14L, 10L, 4L, 11L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 10L)), .Names = c("Date", "G"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("171", "172", "173", "576", 
"577", "578", "579", "580", "581")))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to be easier if you build a little data frame of the data you actually want to plot:

```r
plot_df <- rbind(df1[[1]], df2[[1]])
plot_df$df <- rep(c("df1", "df2"), c(nrow(df1[[1]]), nrow(df2[[1]])))
plot_df$year <- factor(lubridate::year(plot_df$Date))
```

This makes the plotting code much easier and more intuitive:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(Date, !!as.symbol(names(plot_df)[i]), fill = df)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "red")) +
  scale_x_date(labels = function(x) strftime(x, format = "%b %Y")) +
  facet_grid(.~year, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I get an Error when I try to rbind and rep.

Comment: @Mr.Spock as you can see, it works on your example data. Can you tell me what the error is?